# Change font color if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

**Problem**

If the checkbox is checked the font color of the buttons are changing to blue, but if i click one of the other 2 buttons the font color is still orange. 
If the checkbox is unchecked after, the home button will be white instead of orange.

**Code**

```js
var fontcolor = document.getElementsByClassName('color');
var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
var currentActive = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
  cbs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      fontcolor[0].style.color = "#0099ff";
      fontcolor[1].style.color = "#0099ff";
      currentActive[0].style.color = "#0099ff";
    } else {
      fontcolor[0].style.color = "#FF8000";
      fontcolor[1].style.color = "#FF8000";
      currentActive[0].style.color = "#FFF";
    }
  });
};



var tab = document.getElementById('tabs');
var tabs = tab.getElementsByClassName('tab');
for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  tabs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(' active', "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
};
```

```css
.color {
  color: #FF8000;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.tab.active,
.tab:active {
  color: #FF8000;
}

.blue {
  color: #0099FF;
}

.tab {
  background-color: #444;
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 12px 36px;
}
```

```html
<p>Simple <span class="color">Text</span></p>

<div class="tabs" id="tabs">
  <button type="button" id="btn1" class="tab tab-library"><span class="icon icon-menu">Library</span></button>
  <button type="button" id="btn2" class="tab tab-home active"><span class="icon icon-home"></span>Home</button>
  <button type="button" id="btn3" class="tab tab-settings"><span class="icon icon-cog"></span>Settings</button>
</div>

<p><span class="color">Text</span> because Text is cool.</p>

<label class="color-switch"><input type="checkbox" id="check"/><span class="slider round"></span> Color Switch</label>
```

If possible no jQuery.

Comment: How about making the css class .color as a css variable? The check box can then change the value of the variable as needed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Comment: This code is a bit of a mess. I'm not exactly sure where you're learning JS from but perhaps find a different source. You shouldn't be using getElementsByClassName to pull a single element and you constantly are using indices when you don't have to which is mudding up your code.

Comment: @zfrisch Well, being honest here, i kinda learn JS from all over the place, mostly from just looking at codes from other people. Also i'm kinda new to that stuff as it's a hobby and i'm doing it for fun.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hard-coding the style changes, the easiest way might be to create and toggle classes themselves. I've created a few more styles: .orange and .active-blue, and I've removed all references to CSS styles directly. Now, rather than toggling colors, I'm simply toggling orange and blue styles. In the case of the buttons, I'm toggling the activeClass (between 'active' and 'active-blue'), and I've saved that as a variable I can use in the buttons' click handler.

Hope this helps!

```js
var fontcolor = document.getElementsByClassName('color');
var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
var activeClass = "active";


for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
  cbs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    var currentActive = document.getElementsByClassName(activeClass)[0];
    if (this.checked) {
      fontcolor[0].classList.remove("orange");
      fontcolor[1].classList.remove("orange");
      currentActive.classList.remove("active");
      fontcolor[0].classList.add("blue");
      fontcolor[1].classList.add("blue");
      currentActive.classList.add("active-blue");
      activeClass = "active-blue";
    } else {
      fontcolor[0].classList.add("orange");
      fontcolor[1].classList.add("orange");
      currentActive.classList.add("active");
      fontcolor[0].classList.remove("blue");
      fontcolor[1].classList.remove("blue");
      currentActive.classList.remove("active-blue");
      activeClass = "active";
    }
  });
};



var tab = document.getElementById('tabs');
var tabs = tab.getElementsByClassName('tab');
for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  tabs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName(activeClass);
    current[0].classList.remove(activeClass);
    this.classList.add(activeClass);
  });
};
```

```css
.color {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.orange {
  color: #FF8000;
}

.blue {
  color: #0099FF;
}

.tab.active-blue {
  color: #0099FF;
}

.tab.active,
.tab:active {
  color: #FF8000;
}

.tab {
  background-color: #444;
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 12px 36px;
}
```

```html
<p>Simple <span class="color orange">Text</span></p>

<div class="tabs" id="tabs">
  <button type="button" id="btn1" class="tab tab-library">
    <span class="icon icon-menu">Library</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" id="btn2" class="tab tab-home active">
    <span class="icon icon-home">Home</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" id="btn3" class="tab tab-settings">
    <span class="icon icon-cog">Settings</span>
  </button>
</div>

<p><span class="color orange">Text</span> because Text is cool.</p>

<label class="color-switch"><input type="checkbox" id="check"/><span class="slider round"></span> Color Switch</label>
```

Comment: @Keokolor, Did this work out for you? Please either mark it solved, or indicate more info needed, if you would.

Answer (score 0):

You can try alternative way. You should keep all content under the parent `div` Then just add `css` class for switch color. So HTML Like below

**HTML**

```
<div id="switchColor"><!--parent div-->
<p>Simple <span class="color">Text</span></p>

<div class="tabs" id="tabs">
  <button type="button" id="btn1" class="tab tab-library"><span class="icon icon-menu">Library</span></button>
  <button type="button" id="btn2" class="tab tab-home active"><span class="icon icon-home"></span>Home</button>
  <button type="button" id="btn3" class="tab tab-settings"><span class="icon icon-cog"></span>Settings</button>
</div>

<p><span class="color">Text</span> because Text is cool.</p>

<label class="color-switch"><input type="checkbox" id="check"/><span class="slider round"></span> Color Switch</label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.color {
  color: #FF8000;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.tab.active,
.tab:active {
  color: #FF8000;
}

.blue {
  color: #0099FF;
}


.tab {
  background-color: #444;
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 12px 36px;
}

.changeColor .tabs .active, 
.changeColor .color{
    color: #0099FF;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var fontcolor = document.getElementsByClassName('color');
var currentActive = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
var parentDiv = document.getElementById('switchColor');

document.getElementById('check').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
     parentDiv.classList.add('changeColor');
    } else {
      parentDiv.classList.remove('changeColor')
    }
  });



var tab = document.getElementById('tabs');
var tabs = tab.getElementsByClassName('tab');
for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  tabs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(' active', "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
};
```

See the Pen [Color Change Javascript](https://codepen.io/flex4web/pen/eyvmmx/) by Ripon ([@flex4web](https://codepen.io/flex4web)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript and event listeners to do something like this.

```js
var activeBtn = document.getElementById('btn2');
var altColor = false;
document.getElementById('check').addEventListener('change', function() {
  altColor = this.checked;
  activeBtn.style.color = altColor ? 'green' : 'orange';
});

function toggleStyles() {
  activeBtn = this;
  var btns = document.getElementById('tabs').children;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    if (btns[i].id == activeBtn.id) {
      btns[i].style.color = altColor ? 'green' : 'orange';
    } else {
      btns[i].style.color = 'white';
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', toggleStyles);
document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', toggleStyles);
document.getElementById('btn3').addEventListener('click', toggleStyles);
```

```css
.color {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.orange {
  color: #FF8000;
}

.blue {
  color: #0099FF;
}

.tab.active-blue {
  color: #0099FF;
}

.tab.active,
.tab:active {
  color: #FF8000;
}

.tab {
  background-color: #444;
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 12px 36px;
}
```

```html
<p>Simple <span class="color">Text</span></p>

<div class="tabs" id="tabs">
  <button type="button" id="btn1" class="tab tab-library"><span class="icon icon-menu">Library</span></button>
  <button type="button" id="btn2" class="tab tab-home active"><span class="icon icon-home"></span>Home</button>
  <button type="button" id="btn3" class="tab tab-settings"><span class="icon icon-cog"></span>Settings</button>
</div>

<p><span class="color">Text</span> because Text is cool.</p>

<label class="color-switch"><input type="checkbox" id="check"/><span class="slider round"></span> Color Switch</label>
```